# Place html element over exact position in Canvas

Tags: canvas, tags, html5-canvas, position

I have balance value drawn within a canvas.
I want to place a div element over this exact position on the canvas.

I noticed when I resize the window the canvas balance position remain the same.

Can anyone suggest how to convert position of element inside the canvas to a position within the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your code I'm inventing. In the following example I'm drawing a responsive canvas. On the canvas I'm drawing a rectangle, with a white stroke. The bottom right corner of the rectangle is at 100/100 units from the bottom right corner of the canvas.

The HTML text is positioned with CSS over the rectangle. I hope this answer your question.

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth);
let ch = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
ctx.strokeStyle="white";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeRect((cw-100), (ch-100), -200,-50);



function init() {
cw = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth);
ch = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
  ctx.strokeStyle="white";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeRect((cw-100), (ch-100), -200,-50);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  init();
  addEventListener("resize", init, false);
}, 15);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  background: black;
}
div {
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <p>TEXT</p>
</div>
```